# Why does Page width Of My website Differs

Tags: css, web, display

I have a website. The page width is perfect in 15.6 laptops.
But when it comes to larger displays, it gets ruined. Can you please help?
any @media styles to be added? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have written that CSS specially for your screen's resolution. To fix that you need to use media queries. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) {
    width: 1120px;
}
```

I checked and you have a similar problem on smaller screens. You would like to apply a mobile-first strategy, so the layout looks good on all screens. Apply the same strategy (media queries) to set diffences sizes for different resolutions. The most common solution is to use 3 breakpoints. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { }
@media (min-width: 1280px) { }
@media (min-width: 1440px) { }
```

The CSS that you write inside those media-queries will target different screen sizes, but also the CSS in the smallest media-query will work in the next ones if it is not overrriden.

Comment: when i use this instead of enlarging, its kind of moving right so that i have to use margin-left: -ve .

Comment: You can use media-queries to set the CSS you want. If you set a width and margin: auto the content will always be centered, unless there is another element messing with that (some negative margin, for example)

Answer (score 0):

Please give width by % value if you give that in px it will change for different